# Simulate connection failure from asp.mvc to sql server LocalDb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, database-connection, localdb

Is it possible to simulate a connection failure from asp.mvc to sql server LocalDb? 
For example in cases of power outage etc

Thanks in advance
J.